# Angular hangs on app start

Tags: angularjs

My angular application with backend Laravel. Started to hang recently while loading the page half way through. It resolves after sometime and again hangs later. I am getting this error on the console. I use firefox. I dont know how to debug and where to look for the problem?
At the same time if try on a different browser (chrome) it works.

This is the error

```
TypeError: dbg is undefined
```

This error occurs on file debuggerLib.js line 530

```
3 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.1/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
```

This error occurs on file angular.js line 80, col 11

sometimes the number 3 varies to 4 or 2.

How to debug this? Where does this problem occur.

Comment: Could you share some more code? Are you calling $apply or $digest anywhere in your controller?

Comment: Start looking for `dbg` then.

Comment: It should tell you what file the error is occurring in, which should give you a pretty good idea where to start looking.

Comment: I have not use $apply or $digest anywhere. But I use Angular-bootstrap-ui. Those directives might have these. I think so...

Comment: @BenBlack question updated with filename.

Comment: How does the same app works on different browser is that a performance issue on the app?

Comment: could be a race condition. You need to look through the stack trace to figure out why/where the error originates. general javascript debugging. Find the source, then find the *why*

Comment: I found the issue. A function was trying to http.get data from an empty table.